# Getting displacement in meters from "XYZ ECEF" or "NMEA" data

Tags: gps, ecef, cartesian

I am new to this field. I am working on a GNSS receiver that gives me live location data in **NMEA** and **XYZ ECEF** format.

The receiver is mounted on my rover and I wish to use this data to get the rover's displacement in X and Y direction, **in meters**.

Is that possible ? How should I go about it?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: what language are you using and what processor are you using? How accurate do you need the answer to be?